# Html.BeginForm renders different on server than on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm busy deploying a .net MVC 4 Web Application to a server, and it seems that the server is rendering html differently than on localhost.

Example:

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller", FormMethod.Post)){
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
}
```

The Resulting html on localhost:

```
<form action="/Controller/Action" method="post">                 
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

But on the server the html renders like so:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

I made sure the Server is running IIS 7.0, the application pool is also .net 4 (integrated mode). I've even re-installed .net 4 full. I also double checked and all of the dependancy libraries are in the bin folder (those added, when you select "Add Deployable Dependancies")

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean ASP.NET temporary files. Razor might cache compiled views there. You can find more details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx